# Python:How to get correct reference of button in multiple assignment with for loops?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm a beginner programmer and I wanted to learn by a game. I'm trying to make a battleship game with the user clicking on buttons(made using Tkinter) to place battle ships around the board. When I click on buttons I get an error saying the below. How to get the right button int the dictionary choises = {}? The error says:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:\Python Codes\Battleship.py", line 29, in 
>      choice()
>   TypeError: choice() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)

Here is the code I used:

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
screen = tk.Tk(className = "Battle Ship Game" )
screen.geometry("300x300")
screen["bg"] = "white"

line1= list()

def choice(x,y) :
    global choises
    choises = {}

    choises[x] = y
    print choises

def buildaboard1(screen) :
    x = 20
    for n in range(0,10) :
        y = 20
        for i in range(0,10) :
            line1.append(tk.Button(screen ))
            line1[-1]["command"] = (lambda n : choice (x , y))
            line1[-1].place( x = x , y = y+20 , height = 20 , width = 20 )
            y = y+20
        x = x +20


buildaboard1(screen)
choice()
screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: The error is on the second to last line. You're calling `choice()`, but `choice` expects two arguments, `x` and `y`.

Comment: if I pass choice(x , y) on the last line I get another error :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python Codes\Battleship.py", line 29, in <module>
    choice(x , y)
NameError: name 'x' is not defined what do I do? :(

Comment: Why are you calling this function?

Comment: You should go read up on functions and how arguments work :) the choices argument is expecting 2 variables, x and y. If you do not intend sending it those, remove them from the function definition - but then be sure to create them inside the function otherwise you will get that error again.. haha

Comment: `x` and `y` are the names you gave to the arguments of `choice`. You can't call `choice(x, y)` unless `x` and `y` have already been defined, like `x = y = 2`.

Comment: how do I pass the x and y values from that button x and y coordinate? into the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way `Tkinter` assign values from `x` and `y` to `a` and `b`  at once.
And `choice()` will can use it when you press button.

```
line1[-1]["command"] = (lambda a=x, b=y: choice (a , b))
```

This way `Button` want to get values from `x` and `y` when you click it 
but then `x` and `y` don't exist.

```
line1[-1]["command"] = (lambda: choice (x , y))
```